# Launch terminal ro run hangoutbot on raspberry start

Tags: script

I'm a bit newbie in the raspberry world, and Linux commands, etc..

I installed a `hangoutbots` in Raspberry and I launch it in terminal as tutorial said.

But my problem is that I need it to have "24/7", so I need to launch terminal and start automatically if raspberry goes down for some reason.

What I have to do in a terminal to launch the bot, is:

```
>cd DEsktop/BotHangout/hangoutsbot

>python3 hangoutsbot/hangupsbot.py
```

So after all this explanation, my question is:

Is there anyway to launch automatically on raspberry start? (Some type os script, or make  "launcher"...)

Comment: hangoutbots project provides a systemd `.service` file as an example https://github.com/hangoutsbot/hangoutsbot/blob/master/examples/hangupsbot.service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a cronjob by editing your `crontab` file. Here is what you will want to do:

Install `screen`, that way you can resume it in your terminal when you want to. You can install `screen` by entering:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

Then, you will need to enter the command:

```
crontab -e
```

This will open up your `crontab` file, where you will be able to set your startup commands.

At the bottom of the file, add this:

```
@reboot screen -d -m -S Hangoutbot python3 /home/pi/Desktop/BotHangout/hangoutsbot/hangupsbot.py
```

Then save the file with `command x` and then `y` and then enter.

---

**Command Breakdown:**

`@reboot` says to run the following command on startup.

`screen -d -m -S Hangoutbot` says to run the  following command in the background and name the `screen` Hangoutbot.

The rest of the command is the python command that will run your python code.

---

Once booted, the command will be running in the background, if you want to attach it and watch/interact with it, you will need to enter the command:

```
screen -r Hangoutbot
```

Comment: I tried it. I have done all the steps, but when I reboot RPi, it doens't work.(trying to see it with `screen -r Hangoutbot`, bu if I opened a terminal ,and tested just the command `screen -d -m -S ......` this  worked.

Comment: May be is possible it don't work correctly, because I'am accesing to RPi via Tightvnserver ?

Comment: @Shudy it shouldn't matter how you're connected to your Pi. Try `crontab -e` again and make sure that the `crontab` saved.

Comment: sorry to not answer before, I was a bit bussy. Finally I checked the crontab as you said, and It was my Fault. The rute to the *.py file was with a typo. Now it works PERFECT.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your question is an example of "How do I start a program when the Pi boots?" which I believe has been asked and answered a couple of times.  My personal preference for solving this problem is to used `systemd`.  I'd suggest googling around on systemd.  There is also a tutorial video on setting up `systemd` to run an arbitrary command ... see:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEuViHanjKI